# How to remove (nuke) a javax.swing.box entirely?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, box

I have a JPanel that currently has a swing.box in it, which in itself houses an arbitrary number of JButtons.

Now one of the JButtons has the ability to create a new JButton, which goes fine.
However, after creating said new button, I want the button to go in the list at the right position (alphabetically sorted) which also goes fine. I am however sure that it is never the last button as I add some standard buttons at the end.

Now the problem is that I cannot nuke the box that has said buttons in them after which I rebuild the box.

(also see [https://github.com/Diamundo/PhotoSelectorSys/ButtonPanel.java](https://github.com/Diamundo/PhotoSelectorSys/blob/master/src/photoselectorsys/ButtonPanel.java) and specifically at line 42, start of function *initButtons()* )

(problem I also have, is that I add buttons with a preferred size which does take effect if I put them straight in the panel, but not if I put them in the box... so if you have a solution which lets me delete all buttons instead of the box that's also very welcome :D )

```
package photoselectorsys;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {
    private AppFrame listener;
    private String path;
    private Box box;

    public ButtonPanel(int width, int height){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setVisible(true);
        box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    }

    public void setPath(String path){
        this.path = path;
        initButtons();
//        pushButtons();
        this.revalidate();
    }

    /*public void pushButtons() {
        for(JButton jb : buttons) { //buttons was an ArrayList of button names. Is now the box.
            this.remove(jb); //remove the button from the panel.
        }
        for(JButton jb : buttons) { //buttons should be changed to the box
            add(jb);
        }
    }*/

    public void initButtons(){
/*        if(box.hasButtons()) {
            box.nuke();
            box = new Box(..);
        }
*/

        JButton jb;
        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
        ArrayList<String> btns = new ArrayList<>();
        for (File file : listFiles) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                btns.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
        btns.add("Add a new Button");
        btns.add("Rotate CW");
        btns.add("Rotate CCW");
        btns.add("Rotate 180*");

        System.out.println("buttons " + btns.size());
        if(btns.size() > 4) { //if there's at least one folder, size > 4. Else add one big button or ask to create subfolder
            for(String btn : btns) {
                jb = new JButton(btn);
                jb.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                jb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth()-20, 40));
                jb.setVisible(true);

                jb.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                            onButtonPress((JButton) arg0.getSource());
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)  { /* unused */ }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)   { /* unused */ }
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)  { /* unused */ }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { /* unused */ }
                });            
                /*box.*/add(jb);
            }
        } else {
            // do add folder magic from the start.
            jb = new JButton("Add a new Button");
            jb.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            jb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth()-20, this.getHeight()-30));
            jb.setSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth()-20, this.getHeight()));
            jb.setVisible(true);

            jb.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                        onButtonPress((JButton) arg0.getSource());
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)  { /* unused */ }
                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)   { /* unused */ }
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)  { /* unused */ }
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { /* unused */ }
            });            
            /*box.*/add(jb);
        }
//        add(box);
    }

    public void onButtonPress(JButton jb){
// not interesting for this question. See github for function.
    }

    public void addListener(AppFrame listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for your problem, so we can run it and see what's wrong.

Comment: Adding a button at the right position of the children list (or if necessary clearing that list and rebuilding it) as well as invalidating the container component should be sufficient (have a look at the various `add` and `remove` methods, e.g. `add(Component c, int index)` and `removeAll()`) . If not there might be something else that's going wrong like blocking the event dispatch thread etc.

Comment: Sergiy, added code. Thomas, I took a look at remove but didn't understand it (my Java is a bit rusty, but also I haven't worked a lot with adding/removing components when I did code java). I'll have a look at them, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Diamundo Sorry, but the code you've posted is not a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). It has no main method and has some references to another non-JRE classes (for example `AppFrame`).

Comment: Sergiy, I never said I added SSCCE, just the E (I guess). If you want it compilable, look at github (link is included in the first edition of the post). @Thomas can you give an answer with your tip? That worked for me, and then I can select it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the buttons in your box you don't have to create a new box but rather do one of the following 2 things:

a) add the button at the correct position using `box.add( button, index )`
b) remove all buttons using `box.removeAll()` and (re)add the buttons as needed

I'd prefer variant a) but there might be cases where rebuilding the box contents from scratch might be the better way.

Normally that alone should be sufficient since the component should realize it's layout is invalid and needs to be recalculated. If this doesn't happen or you need to revalidate the parent container as well for some reason call the `invalidate()` method on the relevant component.

Comment: revelidate & repaint or JFrame.pack(its can changes JFrames bound)